# 500 server error on form using React Hook Form

Tags: forms, react-hook-form

I made a login form using react hook form. but it has 500 server error constantly.
aws server for testing responds when it receives the same request using Postman.
Form and HTML in snippet below.

```js
function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required('Email is required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  });
  const formOptions = { resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema) };

 
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm(formOptions);
  const { errors, isSubmitting } = formState;
  const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  try{
  console.log(data)
  const req = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(req)
  axios.get(URL + `/login`,
  req, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": `application/json`}
      })
  .then(res => {
    navigate('/');
  console.log(res)})
  } catch (err){
  console.log(err);
  }
}
```

```html
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <InputLabel>Email</InputLabel>
            <InputText
              name="username"
              type="text"
              {...register('email')}
              className={`form-control ${errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            />
            <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email?.message}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <InputLabel>Password</InputLabel>
            <InputText
              name="password"
              type="password"
              {...register('password')}
              className={`form-control ${errors.password ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            />
            <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password?.message}</div>
          </div>
          <InputButton disabled={isSubmitting} className="btn btn-primary">
            {isSubmitting && (
              <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            )}
            Login
          </InputButton>
        </form>
```

And this is the result of `console.log(req)`

```json
{"email":"qwerty4@gmail.com","password":"fgdggggfgddR1!"}
```

request is JSON format, and the key value is the same as required by the server.
I added the onInvalid parameter to onSubmit but it's still failed..I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using axios.post instead of axios.get